# Laravel redirect route with a parameter from controller

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-routing

I'm trying to redirect a route from a controller function after a form submit process in Laravel 5.4 as it is said in link below

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects#redirecting-named-routes

**Route;**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api'], 'prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::post('doSomething', 'Page@doSomething');
});


Route::post('/profile', function () {
    //..
});
```

**Controller;**

```
public function doSomething(Request $request){
   return redirect()->route('profile', ['id'=>1]);
}
```

When I try to redirect I get this error.

> InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 304: Route [profile]
>   not defined.

I have searched several times about redirection but I got similar results.

Any suggestions ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`route()` works with named routes, so name your route

```
Route::post('/profile', function () {
//..
})->name('profile');
```